# Using javascript function argument to return object value

Tags: javascript

Javascript function that takes a single argument. Use that argument value which is a string to return the appropriate value from the matched object key.

```
 function someFunction(someArg) {

var message = {
    bob: "Hello bob",
    mike: "Hello mike",
    tara: "Hello tara"
}

console.log(message +  " " + message.someArg + " " + someArg + " " + message.bob);
```

}

what is returned is

```
 [object Object] undefined bob Hello bob
```

Where undefined is returned in the console log, JavaScript should return the message "Hello bob" as the value of someArg is "bob", calling message.bob returns the correct result.

Comment: `return message[someArg];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `message.someArg` you are "telling" attribute someArg or your message Object.

What you have to use is `message[someArg]` to get the dynamic property.

Answer (score 2):

To print it properly, you'll have to:

- Stringify the message object
- Refer to the property of message in a correct manner

Try this

```
function someFunction(someArg) {
   var message = {
    bob: "Hello bob",
    mike: "Hello mike",
    tara: "Hello tara"
   }
   //ES6
   console.log(`${JSON.stringify(message)} ${message[someArg]} ${someArg} ${message.bob}`);
   //ES5
   console.log(JSON.stringify(message) +  " " + message[someArg] + " " + someArg + " " + message.bob);

}
```

Now, on calling *someFunction('bob')*, the output is:

```
{"bob":"Hello bob","mike":"Hello mike","tara":"Hello tara"} Hello bob bob Hello bob
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [] notation, where obj[key] is the same as obj.key, but key can be a variable.

```js
function someFunction(someArg) {

  var message = {
    bob: "Hello bob",
    mike: "Hello mike",
    tara: "Hello tara"
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(message) + " " + message[someArg] + " " + someArg + " " + message.bob);

}


someFunction("mike");
```